# Why does a video larger than 8176 x 4088 created using AVFoundation come out with a uniform dark green color on my Mac?

Tags: macos, animation, cocoa, avfoundation, macos-catalina

When I use AVFoundation to create an 8K (7680 x 4320) MP4 with frames directly drawn onto pixel buffers obtained from the pixel buffer pool, it works with `kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB`.

However if I use `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`, the entire video has a **uniform dark green color** instead of the actual contents. This problem occurs for resolutions above **8176 x 4088**.

What could be causing this problem?

AVAssetWriter.h [in SDK 10.15](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/blob/master/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AVAssetWriterInput.h#L769) and [in SDK 11.3](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/blob/master/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AVAssetWriterInput.h#L770) says:

> The H.264 encoder natively supports ... If you need to work in the RGB domain then `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` is recommended on iOS and `kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB` is recommended on OSX.

AVAssetWriter.h [in SDK 12.3](https://github.com/realjf/MacOSX-SDKs/blob/master/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AVAssetWriterInput.h#L773) however says:

> The H.264 and HEVC encoders natively support ... If you need to work in the RGB domain then `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` is recommended on iOS and macOS.

AVAssetWriter.h on all three SDKs however also says:

> If you are working with high bit depth sources the following yuv pixel formats are recommended when encoding to ProRes: `kCVPixelFormatType_4444AYpCbCr16`, `kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr16`, and `kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr10`. When working in the RGB domain `kCVPixelFormatType_64ARGB` is recommended.

Whatever be the recommendations, the below prelude states that all of them are just for optimal performance and not for error free encoding!

> For optimal performance the format of the pixel buffer should match one of the native formats supported by the selected video encoder. Below are some recommendations:

Now, Keynote movie export with H.264 compression also results in the same problem with the same size limits on my [Mid-2012 15-inch Retina MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp653) running Catalina (supports upto Keynote 11.1). This problem doesn't occur on a later Mac running Monterey where the latest version 12.2 of Keynote is supported.

I have not included code because Keynote movie export is a simple means to reproduce and understand the problem.

My motivation for asking this question is to obtain clarity on:

1. What is the right pixel format to use for MP4 creation?
2. What are safe size limits under which MP4 creation will be problem free?